# Java CSV Reader, reading remaining data

Tags: java, csv, import-from-csv

I have CSV data as following:

```
1,mm/dd/yy,"abc,def,"pqr",xyz"
```

I would like to have this parsed into 3 strings.

1. 1
2. mm/dd/yy
3. all remaining data, in this case, "abc,def,"pqr",xyz"

I have tried several libraries, openCSV, javacsv etc.
all of them seems to parse and tokenize last column as well. 
What I want is remaining data after second column as a single token.

Any ideas ?

Comment: your CSV it is not real CSV as per rfc4180, the quotes are wrong.. That is why opencsv will not parse it correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should update the input data to enclose the 3rd column with single quote, like the following:
1,mm/dd/yy,'abc,def,"pqr",xyz'

Otherwise, you will never resolve the csv data correctly.

With the updated data, you can call the powerful open source library [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to read the data correctly in just several lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // 1st, config the CSV reader
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    settings.getFormat().setQuote('\'');        // set the quote to single quote '
    settings.getFormat().setQuoteEscape('\\');  // escape the double quote "

    // 2nd, creates a CSV parser with the configs
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    // 3rd, parses all rows from the CSV file into a 2-dimensional array
    List<String[]> resolvedData = parser.parseAll(new StringReader("1,mm/dd/yy,'abc,def,\"pqr\",xyz'"));
    for (String[] row : resolvedData) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String col : row) {
            strBuilder.append(col).append("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(strBuilder);
    }
}
```

And you will get output like this:

> 1    mm/dd/yy    abc,def,"pqr",xyz

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstCommaIndex = s.indexOf(',');
int secondCommaIndex = s.indexOf(',', firstCommaIndex + 1);
String firstPart = s.substring(0, firstCommaIndex);
String secondPart = s.substring(firstCommaIndex + 1, secondCommaIndex);
String lastPart = s.substring(secondCommaIndex + 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for writing. But how efficient is that ? I got more than 40K records in single csv

Comment: It's as efficient as any CSV parser you could use, and which would probably do basically the same thing. The performance is irrelevant anyway, since the limiting factor will be IO, and not processor speed. And 40K records is not a very large number anyway. On my box, it takes 44 milliseconds to do the above 40,000 times on your example string. And without letting the chance to the JIT to compile and optimize the code. Don't pre-optimize, it's the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html). It has *quoteChar* configuration option which seems to express handling of quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom LineParser on https://github.com/CyborTronik/fluent-ssv

And it as well will transform your CSV data into beans, but for date type you will need to provide a custom implementation of ValueConverter, otherwise you can store it as string and then manipulate it.

So code will look like:

```
new SsvStreamBuilder<MyBean>()
  .forEntity(MyBean.class)
  .withLineParser(new MyLineParser())
  .withValueConverter(new MyDateConverter())
  .stream("~/some/csv/file");
```