# Java read specific parts of a CSV

Tags: java, csv

I created the following code to read a CSV-file:

```
public void read(String csvFile) {
   try {
      File file = new File(csvFile);
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      String line = "";
      String[] tempArr;
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        tempArr = line.split(ABSTAND);
        anzahl++;
        for(String tempStr : tempArr) {
          System.out.print(tempStr + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    br.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
       ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have a CSV with more than 300'000 lines that look like that:
{9149F314-862B-4DBC-B291-05A083658D69};Gebaeude;TLM_GEBAEUDE;;Schiessstand;{41C949A2-9F7B-41EE-93FD-631B76F2176D};***Altdorf*** 300m;offiziell;Hochdeutsch inkl. Lokalsprachen;Einfacher Name;;***684600***;***295930***;400

How can I now only get the some parts out of that? I only need the bold/italic parts to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java CSV Reader, reading remaining data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892894/java-csv-reader-reading-remaining-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further specifying what your requirements/input limitations are the following should work within your loop.

```
        String str = "{9149F314-862B-4DBC-B291-05A083658D69};Gebaeude;TLM_GEBAEUDE;;Schiessstand;{41C949A2-9F7B-41EE-93FD-631B76F2176D};Altdorf 300m;offiziell;Hochdeutsch inkl. Lokalsprachen;Einfacher Name;;684600;295930;400";
        String[] arr = str.split("[; ]", -1);
        int cnt=0;

//        for (String a : arr)
//            System.out.println(cnt++ + ": " + a);
        System.out.println(arr[6] + ", " + arr[15] + ", " + arr[16]);
```

Note that this assumes your delimiters are either a semicolon or a space and  that the fields desired are in the fix positions (6, 15, 16).
Result:

```
Altdorf, 684600, 295930
```